# python3 tkinter or ncurses

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, ncurses

I want to impliment some kind of UI for my Python programs (some simple operations, nothing advanced).
So I looked around and considered ncurses and tkinter for python. Yet I am not sure which of these two would suit best my needs for a simple interface (in the sense of easy to learn to program) with the best output possibilies. It does not have to be fancy or anything, just help me visualise my code (lets say a text based chess game).

intuitively i would take tkinter, but could you probably just summarise for me the advantages of the two UIs? (in addition ncurses does not seem to have a good tutorial for python...)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4):

I would like to suggest tkinter as it comes with python and compare to other GUI packages it has good tutorials. And also it will help you to improve your OOP concept for python

Comment: yeah tkinter is also my favorite. if i understood it right tkinter uses gtk+ right? So hypothetically i could create windows which perfectly integrate into my gnome environment?

Comment: @kyril: no, tkinter does not use gtk+. It uses tk, completely unrelated except for sharing two letters in the name.

Comment: darn, okay thanks, must have misread it. Is there actually a GUI for python which uses gtk+?

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on using your application across platforms, Tkinter or PyQt are both good choices. If you want a GTK+ application that matches your GNOME environment and don't plan on using the application on other platforms, then I would suggest using GTK+ via gobject-introspection (from pygobject). In Fedora, you should have support for it out of the box. Other distributions may require the installation of additional packages.

For more information on the above bindings, see:

- [TkDocs](http://www.tkdocs.com/)
- [The Python GTK+ 3 Tutorial](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

(Sorry I couldn't post a link for PyQt because I don't have enough reputation to post more than 2 links.)

Additionally, it's worth noting that both PyQt and GTK+ have interface designers available so that you don't have to create your interfaces programmatically if you don't want to. For PyQt I believe Qt Creator comes with an interface designer. For GTK+ you have Glade.